# Simple Python animation using pause command not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

I wanted to create a simple animation using plt.pause() command in python. So I tried the first example from [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-animations-in-python/) page. If you go there, it shows you a nice animation of a graph growing smoothly. I copy-paste it below

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
x = []
y = []
for i in range(100):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i)

# Mention x and y limits to define their range
    plt.xlim(0, 100)
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
  
# Ploting graph
    plt.plot(x, y, color = 'green')
    plt.pause(0.01)
plt.show()
```

However, it is giving me 100 different plots with an incremental increase until it completes the range. I think the problem is with figures appearing without waiting for the plt.show() command? Help me. I am using Jupiter 6.0.3 and sypder 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `.show()` command the plot will disappear at the completion of the code. however the animation should still be visible as it is created by the `.plot()` command.

I am not able to reproduce your problem using `Python 3.9.7`.

You can always try running the script outside of the IDE using `python pathtoscript` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: It worked when I ran it from the terminal directly. Thanks.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to save it as a video/gif? I see examples where they use animation module to make animations. But here it isn't the case.

Comment: Unfortunately no, sorry

Answer (score 1):

To build on @Regretful's answer, if you're running in a Jupyter notebook, use `%matplotlib qt` or some other non-inline backend to get the usual pop-up window, rather than static images.

No idea for Spyder, though!